# Remote SP Call via Linked Servers. Asynchronous or not?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, asynchronous, linked-server

I have set up 2 servers which are linked. From my LOCAL SERVER, I am executing a SP that will be run on the REMOTE SERVER.

The next part of the script requires me to INSERT DATA from the changes made via the SP on the REMOTE SERVER to the LOCAL SERVER.

Therefore my question is, is this process asynchronous or synchronous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify otherwise it's all synchronous.

[This](http://csharpfeeds.com/post.aspx?id=1570) is how you call sps asynchronously from C# 
(note -->

```
new SqlConnection(connectionstring + "async=true;");
```

).

[This](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/10894_3427581_2/Submitting-A-Stored-Procedure-Asynchronously.htm) is one way to call sps asynchronously from T-SQL.

All the above just to show that if you're *simply calling* the sps it's all synchronous (the caller waits for the callee to return).

Comment: How do I specify it otherwise? BTW, is there a link you could provide so I can do a bit more reading up on this? Cheers!

Comment: see edit, those links are a good start - if you master asynchronous calls you'll be always one step ahead :)

Comment: it looks a bit beyond my level of sql skills for the moment. but thanks for the up vote too :P

Comment: hmm how do i change the status of the question as 'answered'?

Comment: +1, I hate getting the correct accepted answer, but no up votes!